# how to call ajax pagination function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've succeeded display the data what I want based on the select box, but why is my pagination not working?

[The index.php display with pagination not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/654QD.png)

this is my ajax script to load data and pagination function

```
<div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="table-responsive" id="show-level"></div>
        </div>    
      </div>
  </body>
</html>

<!---jQuery ajax load rcords using select box --->
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      load_data();  
       function load_data(page){
       $(".level").on("change", function(){
         var levelname = $(this).val();
         if (levelname !== "") {
           $.ajax({
             url : "display.php",
             type:"POST",
             cache:false,
             data:{levelname:levelname, page:page},
             success:function(data){
               $("#show-level").html(data);
             }
           });
         }else{
           $("#show-level").html(" ");
         }
       });
     }
       $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(){  
            var page = $(this).attr("id");  
            load_data(page);  
       });
   });
</script>
```

and then this is my **display.php** where the pagination function is set

```
$output .= "</table>";
          $page_query = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE level = 'sulit'";  
          $page_result = mysqli_query($con, $page_query);  
          $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($page_result);  
          $total_pages = ceil($total_records/$record_per_page);  
          for($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++)  
          {  
          $output .= "<span class='pagination_link' style='cursor:pointer; padding:6px; border:1px solid #ccc;' id='".$i."'>".$i."</span>";  
          }  
 $output .= '</div><br /><br />';
          echo $output;
     }else{
          echo "No records found";
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$records_per_page` is 10, and the number of total records is 100, the below will always give you the first 10 items.

```
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($page_result);  
$total_pages = ceil($total_records/$record_per_page); 
for($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
  ...
```

You should look at limiting the number of results and offsetting them in your SQL instead. For instance, you can limit your number of rows to 10, and then offset the results by the page number you are currently on (*10).

Here is what the statement would look like for page 2:

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE level = 'sulit' LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

So your code *could* look something like (I haven't tested this - but I think it should be about right):

```
$offset = $current_page * $records_per_page;
$page_query = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE level = 'sulit' LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
$page_result = mysqli_prepare($con, $page_query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($page_result, 'ii', $records_per_page, $offset);
mysqli_stmt_execute($page_query);
```